# Using a while loop function return string from text file Python

Tags: python, file, while-loop

This function contains a file "file.txt" which contains the txt "Hello World!" What i need to do is open the file and use a while loop to build and return the phrase from the file and the last word ("World!") x number of times on new lines.

The while loop is essential

Any other ways without the while loop would help too

```
def echo(fname, x):
    fname = open("file.txt",'r')
    text = fname.read()
    return text
    i=1
    while i <= x:
        return text[:6]
        i +=1
```

Here is the question and the result it should produce.

Write a function that takes a single string represting a file name as an argument and a number, x. Open the file and use a while loop and return a string containing the phrase from the file and the last word x times.

```
def echo(fname, x):
"""
>>>echo("file.txt", 2)
"Hello World!:\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\n
>>> echo("file.txt", 4)
"Hello World!:\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\nWorld!\\n
"""
```

Comment: Why is the while loop essential?

Comment: It's asked for in this question I'm doing

Comment: while loop doesn't make much sense here. Could you post the actual question, so that we could interpret it ourselves?

Comment: I have added the question and the result it should produce

Comment: You should learn about what `return` does and then edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file always has one line:

```
def echo(filename, repeats):
    with open(filename) as f:
        txt = f.read()  # this is normally ugly, but since we're presupposing
                        # one-line files, let's run with it....
    last_word = txt.split()[-1]
    result = "\n".join([txt] + [last_word] * repeats)
    return result
```

Use of a `while` loop is silly here. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the while loop

```
def echo(fname, x):
    with open(fname) as f:
        line = f.readline()

    retlst = [line]

    i = 0
    words = line.split()
    while i < x:
        retlst.extend(words[-1:])
        i += 1

    return '\n'.join(retlst)

print echo("filewhl.txt", 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question-as-asked. I try very hard to avoid giving programmers the wrong way to do it just because that's what their homework assignment requires.

Comment: Hopefully the OP can see both answer side by side and realise the while loop is not using python how it should be used.